# Entity Framework GroupBy throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to `GroupBy` my results based on a joined table.

```
var services = await db.Services.AsNoTracking()
    .Include("Visit")
    .Where(s => !s.Cancelled && s.AmtToPay > 0 && patientIds.Contains(s.Visit.PatientNo) && s.DTS < day)
    .GroupBy(s => s.Visit.PatientNo)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Unfortunately this `GroupBy` causes an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase' which is being passed as an argument to the method 'ValueBufferTryReadValue'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider assigning this constant to a local variable and using the variable in the query instead. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2103067 for more information.

Which doesn't really explain the situation. How do I use `GroupBy` in this situation?

Comment: Can you share `patientIds` variable?

Comment: @okankaradag it's a `List<string>` with a few items. If I drop the group clause, I get the results just fine.

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: It's EF core 5.

Comment: Same behaviour in EF core 6.

Answer (score 1):

`select` should be added after `groupby` in EntityFramework Core

```
var services = await db.Services.AsNoTracking()
    .Include("Visit")
    .Where(s => !s.Cancelled && s.AmtToPay > 0 && patientIds.Contains(s.Visit.PatientNo) && s.DTS < day)
    .GroupBy(s => s.Visit.PatientNo)
    .Select(s => s.Key)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

according to [ef core 3.1 breaking changes notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client)

> Starting with 3.0, EF Core only allows expressions in the top-level
> projection (the last Select() call in the query) to be evaluated on
> the client. When expressions in any other part of the query can't be
> converted to either SQL or a parameter, an exception is thrown.

Comment: This does work. To be honest, I don't fully understand the difference, but... I'm glad it works.

Comment: To be precise, one of the things I don't understand is why `.Select(s => s.Key)` works, but `.Select(s => s)` does not.

Comment: @viraptor output of `.Select(s => s)` is `Select * from [table] group by [column]`, which is an incorrect translation. s.Key is groupped values. the output is like `Select Id .... group by Id`